# Sound does not stop after swiping in ViewPager and slow app

Tags: android, audio, view, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

Im still a beginner in developing app. Im trying to swipe through my viewPager which displays a picture and also a button. When the button is pressed, sound will be played according to the pic(I'm using case). It works, when i swipe, the previous sound stops, but when i press the button again, the following sound does not play. I think there is some trouble in OnPageChangeListener. Secondly, my app works fine without sound initially, but after adding sounds in the viewPager, the whole system seems to be slow and it blackouts and hangs often. Please do help me to solve this situation. Thank you so much guys.

```
int position;

OnPageChangeListener player;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set title for the ViewPager
    //setTitle("ViewPager");
    // Get the view from view_pager.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
    final ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
    //
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_alarm);
    final MediaPlayer cpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_ignition);
    final MediaPlayer fpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.helicopter);
    final MediaPlayer ffButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.motorcycle);

    //
    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent p = getIntent();
    position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ImageAdapterchap1 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapterchap1(this);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();




    // Retrieve all the images
    for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        images.add(imageView);


    // Set the images into ViewPager
    ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);

    viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);

    // Show images following the position
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);



    Button info=(Button) findViewById(R.id.audio);
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (viewpager.getCurrentItem()) {
        case 0:
            mpButtonClick.start();

            // do something
            break;
        case 1:
            cpButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 2:
            fpButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 3:
            ffButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 4:
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }

    });

    }
    OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
        {
            ffButtonClick.stop();
            mpButtonClick.stop();
            cpButtonClick.stop();
            fpButtonClick.stop();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {

        }
    };

    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);

}




public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
{
    ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (View)view );
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
    {
        ffButtonClick.stop();
        mpButtonClick.stop();
        cpButtonClick.stop();
        fpButtonClick.stop();

    }
```

To:

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
    {
        ffButtonClick.pause();
        ffButtonClick.seekTo(0);
        mpButtonClick.pause();
        mpButtonClick.seekTo(0);
        cpButtonClick.pause();
        cpButtonClick.seekTo(0);
        fpButtonClick.pause();
        fpButtonClick.seekTo(0);
    }
```

Since stopping a MediaPlayer also unloads the audio and you should use `.prepare()` again. Also, a better solution would be to have a `lastPage` instance variable to save the last selected page of the ViewPager and use an if or a switch to just pause and seek to the beginning to the data that MediaPlayer.

Comment: I have tried the following code, but it just pauses the current sound, but when i swipe to the following page, there is no sound and when i press the button, there is no sound.